# Scaling webforms

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have a webforms app hosted as an azure website. When I add customers to the application I need to add 2-3 aspx pages specific to them. If the customer count grows to a large number say 1000 is there anything I need to worry about with having that many aspx pages (2000 to 3000)?

I just want to know if the approach I am taking is ok before things get large.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you should worry about maintenance. Imagine what would happen if you need to change a simple thing on all those pages.

If this is really a requirement, try to see if you can generalize it. Maybe you have enough when you have a list of fields specified in the database for every customer. If you can dynamically generate those fields, maybe you only need 1 page.

Comment: There is some common code I have in a user control however for everything else It really does very wildly by customer so I think dynamically generating the content and using one web form is out the window. There would never be a chance I would need to change 1 thing that is common across all the pages since they are all customer specific (other than what I have in my user control which is shared). I am more asking if there is any limitations to how many aspx pages or files you can have within one web form application.

Comment: Of course the number of pages can outnumber the resources you have, but besides that, it will work.

Comment: Thanks Patrick. I know it sounds wild but if I get that number of users it would definitely be a good thing so just making sure if this route is feasible before I get there.

Comment: It is feasible to me. You just need a lot of time to maintain it all. If the customer pays, good for you ;)

Answer (score 0):

I would rethink the design of your system, why are you adding pages for users? 
Why isn't the data bound to the page and displayed based on the users so all 3000 users have the same page but different data.

Do you have a site map? User Roles?

Comment: aaron basically I am taking tempates the users give me (example is a word doc) and converting them into web forms... A template from user A can be completely different than user B so each user has their own database tables as well... So yes I guess I could use one aspx file and add a panel for each user and only display that specific panel for the logged in user however I personally think maintaining that  would be harder than keeping the users  web forms separate.

Comment: The odd things we are asked to do.. =D. I have a web form application that is several GB in size (source files.. not photos.. not data) everything runs great. Thousands of users and hundreds of pages as well as dynamically generated pages. The only issue I ran into was some pages were placed in the wrong folders.. determine your folder layout and stick to it as long as thats in place webforms works great... i tried to do this in MVC but it just didnt work well.